# Password cannot contain Q or Z

Tags: passwords

I saw [this interesting page](http://help.jetblue.com/SRVS/CGI-BIN/webisapi.dll?New,Kb=askBlue,case=obj(403864)) on JetBlue's help pages. It says the following:

> Passwords:
>
> - (Typical password restrictions).
> - Cannot contain a Q or Z

Why would they not allow specific characters in their passwords? Does it have something to the way passwords are hashed?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57909/why-would-you-not-permit-q-or-z-in-passwords).

Comment: The earlier question on Security.SE has a good accepted answer. This one should probably be closed.

Comment: It is a duplicate, but on a different site... How do mods handle that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Archaic holdover - probably that's why, look at the picture: [image]

Comment: What even is that thing?

Comment: Good question stib - it looks a bit like a phone but instead of the mouthpiece being a trumpet into the wall box, they appear to have developed a combined mouthpiece/earpiece to make this more portable. The wonders of modern technological advances eh!